# Database Normalization confusion?

Tags: sql, normalization

I have 5 tables:

1. tblProvince
2. tblDivison
3. tblDistrict
4. tblCity
5. tblconstituency

`tblProvince`:

- ID
- Name
- Area

`TblDivision`:

- ID
- Name
- Area
- Province_id

`tblDistrict`:

- ID
- Name
- Area
- Province_id
- Division_id

`tblCity`:

- ID
- Name
- Area
- Province_id
- Division_id
- District_id

`TblConstituency`:

- ID
- Name
- Area
- Province_id
- Division_id
- District_id
- City_id

Is this the right way to store data? adding complete detail of the Area.

Or should I just save the id of the previous area (like city is the container of constituency). to store detail of constituency i should ad city_id with it.

like this...

```
tblCity
+-------------+
| ID          |
+-------------+
| Name        |
+-------------+
| Area        |
+-------------+
| District_id |
+-------------+

TblConstituency
+-------------+
| ID          |
+-------------+
| Name        |
+-------------+
| Area        |
+-------------+
| City_id     |
+-------------+
```

and if i want to get complete detail about constituency i could get id of city, and from city i could get district, and from district i could get division and so on.

But, I feel its a massive overkill. it will be a long query every time i need to get detail.

So, what's the best way?

P.S: apologies for poor way of describing my question.

Comment: what is this Area field done for? You might have missed a TblArea, made out of an ID field, and a AreaName field. You should then add an Area_Id in the TblProvince table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never store the same information twice.  This means you would have to *manually* keep that information synchronized, and synchronization is difficult and error-prone.  Basically, any time you have multiple sources of truth, you have zero sources of truth.

Consider your tables here:

```
Division
+-------------+
| ID          |
+-------------+
| Name        |
+-------------+
| Area        |
+-------------+
| Province_id |
+-------------+



District
+-------------+
| ID          |
+-------------+
| Name        |
+-------------+
| Area        |
+-------------+
| Province_id |
+-------------+
| Division_id |
+-------------+
```

`Division` is already storing the `Province_id`.  So why does `District` need to store it as well?  What happens if `District` stores a *different* `Province_id` than its corresponding `Division` record?  Which one is correct for that `District`?

Just link to the direct parent record:

```
District
+-------------+
| ID          |
+-------------+
| Name        |
+-------------+
| Area        |
+-------------+
| Division_id |
+-------------+
```

The information, by relation to the `Division` table, already exists and can be queried.  (Basically, that's what the `JOIN` keyword is for.)  Since you already have the information, you don't need to repeat it.

Answer (score 1):

Normalization through BCNF is based on functional dependencies. What
are the functional dependencies in data like this? What are the
candidate keys?

```
Cities
State       County       City
--
Alabama     Pike         Troy
Arkansas    Pike         Delight
Florida     Bay          Springfield
Maine       Penobscot    Springfield
```

Here there's only one (trivial) functional dependency and only one
candidate key. The only FD is State, County, City -> State, County,
City. The only candidate key is {State, County, City}. This relation
is in at least 5NF.

You *can't* improve this relation, but you *can* improve the
database. The database doesn't know that there's no county named "Los
Angeles" in Alabama. So it will let you insert this invalid row.

```
Cities
State       County       City
--
Alabama     Los Angeles  Troy
```

To fix *that* problem, add a relation containing all the valid
counties, and set a foreign key reference.

```
Counties
State
--
Alabama     Autauga
Alabama     Baldwin
...
Alabama     Pike
...
California  Los Angeles
...
```

The relation "Counties" is all key, and it has no non-prime
attributes. "Counties" is also in at least 5NF.

The database still doesn't know that it shouldn't allow rows like this.

```
Cities
State    County  City
--
Wales    Pike    Troy
```

There's no state named *Wales* in the USA. Fix this problem the same
way as the last problem.

```
States
--
Alabama
Arkansas
...
California
...
```

And set a foreign key reference from Counties to States.

Here's what it would look like in standard SQL, except that I didn't
supply all 50 states or all 3000+ counties.

```
create table states (
  state varchar(100) primary key
);

insert into states values 
('Alabama'), ('Arkansas'), ('California'), ('Florida'), 
('Maine'); -- and more . . .

create table counties (
  county varchar(100) not null,
  state varchar(100) not null,
  primary key (county, state),
  foreign key (state) references states (state)
    on update restrict on delete restrict
);

insert into counties values
('Autauga', 'Alabama'), ('Baldwin', 'Alabama'), ('Pike', 'Alabama'), 
('Pike', 'Arkansas'), 
('Los Angeles', 'California'),
('Bay', 'Florida'), 
('Penobscot', 'Maine'); -- and more . . .

create table cities (
  city varchar(100) not null,
  county varchar(100) not null,
  state varchar(100) not null,
  primary key (city, county, state),
  foreign key (county, state) references counties (county, state)
    on update restrict on delete restrict
);

insert into cities values 
('Troy', 'Pike', 'Alabama'),
('Delight', 'Pike', 'Arkansas'),
('Springfield', 'Penobscot', 'Maine'),
('Springfield', 'Bay', 'Florida'); -- and more . . .
```

Now you'll find that it's impossible to insert the invalid tuples
{Troy, Los Angeles, Alabama} and {Troy, Pike, Wales}.

Using surrogate ID numbers instead of natural keys doesn't change the
normal forms. But it *does* change how the database works. And not
necessarily in a good way.

Using the SQL tables above, this update will fail.

```
update states
set state = 'Wibble'
where state = 'Alabama';
```

And that's a Good Thing.

Let's build these tables with surrogate ID numbers instead.

```
create table states (
  state_id integer primary key,
  state varchar(100) not null unique
);

insert into states values 
(1, 'Alabama'), (2, 'Arkansas'), (3, 'California'), (4, 'Florida'), 
(5, 'Maine'); -- and more . . .

create table counties (
  county_id integer not null,
  county varchar(100) not null,
  state_id integer not null, 
  foreign key (state_id) references states (state_id) 
    on update restrict on delete restrict,
  primary key (county_id, state_id),
  unique (county, state_id)
);

insert into counties values
(1, 'Autauga', 1), (2, 'Baldwin', 1), (3, 'Pike', 1), 
(4, 'Pike', 2), 
(5, 'Los Angeles', 3),
(6, 'Bay', 4), 
(7, 'Penobscot', 5); -- and more . . .


create table cities (
  city_id integer not null,
  city varchar(100) not null,
  county_id integer not null,
  state_id integer not null,
  foreign key (county_id, state_id) references counties (county_id, state_id)
    on update restrict on delete restrict,
  primary key (city_id, county_id, state_id),
  unique (city, county_id, state_id)
);

insert into cities values 
(1, 'Troy', 3, 1),
(2, 'Delight', 4, 2),
(3, 'Springfield', 7, 5),
(4, 'Springfield', 6, 4); -- and more . . .
```

All three of these tables are still in at least 5NF. But this
(invalid) update will now succeed.

```
update states
set state = 'Wibble'
where state = 'Alabama';
```

That's a Bad Thing.

Using surrogate ID numbers makes every foreign key reference
have the same behavior as declaring them `on update cascade`. To recover
part of the semantics of `on update restrict`, you have to take the
extra, unintuitive step of revoking update permissions on the
referenced tables.

Almost *nobody* gets that part right.

---

There's no realtional principle that justifies splitting primary keys
in order to have a path you *can* follow to recover the original
relation. In other words, there's no *relational* principle that
justifies changing this...

```
Cities
city_id  city  county_id state_id
--
1        Troy  3         2
```

...to this.

```
Cities
city_id  city   county_id 
--
1        Troy   3
```

```
Counties
county_id county  state_id
--
3         Pike    1
```

Not only is there *no* relational principle that justifies splitting
primary keys, it *creates* one of the problems the relational model of
data intended to solve. Look up "IMS", a hierarchical database
management system that requires the user to follow paths through the
data files.

Answer (score 0):

And just to clarify on the other answer and remove the redundancy, this might clarify with respective query/joins.  I am renaming columns to ensure clarification on context but may be missing context of your "Area" fiel

```
tblProvince:     ( ID, ProvinceName, Area )
TblDivision:     ( ID, DivisionName, ProvinceID )
tblDistrict:     ( ID, DistrictName, DivisionID )
tblCity:         ( ID, CityName, DistrictID )
TblConstituency: ( ID, ConstituencyName, CityID )

select
      Con.ConstituencyName, 
      City.CityName,
      Dis.DistrictName,
      Div.DivisionName,
      Prov.ProvinceName,
      Prov.Area
   from
      tblConstituency Con
         JOIN tblCity City
            on Con.CityID = City.ID
            JOIN tblDistrict Dis
               on City.DistrictID = Dis.ID
               JOIN tblDivision Div
                  on Dis.DivisionID = Div.ID
                  JOIN tblProvince Prov
                     on Div.ProvinceID = Prov.ID
```

and notice the hierarchical representation of the JOINS from one table to the next.  You see the direct correlation of tables.   Then just apply a WHERE clause if you are looking for specific area in question.