# Tables Hierarchy in a database

Tags: sql, database, relational-database

I am not sure if this is the right forum to ask this question but am assuming it is a technical question so posting here.

It was asked during an interview that;

We have 4 tables.. Country, City, District, Sub District. How to make hierarchy of them in database ( One way is adding foreign reference of parent in child table... but what's the other way?)

I am not able to find any other way but to add all the information in one table but the question was 'how to make **hierarchy** of them' ? which means multiple tables are involved.

Could anyone please suggest what could be the other way?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/35699997/562459

Comment: Interviewer asked, "without making foreign refernece of parent in child table" and the solutions provided in the mentioned thread have parents' reference.

Comment: *"without making foreign refernece of parent in child table"*: that's not in your question. Maybe you should edit your question to clearly and explicitly include the entire question.

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' I already mentioned " ( One way is adding foreign reference of parent in child table... but what's the other way?)"

Comment: There's more than one way to express a hierarchy with foreign key  references. So far, nobody seems to understand that you're only interested in solutions using one table (?) and no foreign key references. If that's what you want, edit your question and say so, clearly and directly.

Answer (score 0):

Tgere are a lot of approaches. Some of them good from the normalisation point of view, some from performance and easy to use point of view. Some of them:

- Self reference:

[image]

- Code holds information. for example 123000 - is a district, 123001 -
  001 sub district of district 123

[image]

- The most normalised way (link district-city can be changed to
  subdistrict-city)

[image]

Comment: Not able to understand the solution as Interviewer asked, "without making foreign reference of parent in child table" and all three solutions provided have parents' reference or did I get the solutions wrong?

Comment: @HappyDev, provide detailed description please! How many tables should be? If 1, just put all info into 1 table, and you will have absolutely de normalized store. If it should be more then 1 table, you should reference data from one table to other. If you don't want to use FK, you can use approach like in example 2) where child and parent have codes 123000 and 123001